# updating an entity in entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4

I have an entity (`TerminalCertification`) which has relation to other entities.
I want to make user to be able to update `TerminalCertification` but I'm not able to update related object which is updated by user. My update code is here:

```
public void UpdateTerminalCertification(TerminalCertification terminalCertification)
{
    var lastCertification = db.terminalCertifications.Find(terminalCertification.TerminalCertificationID);

    if (lastCertification==null)
        throw new TerminalCertificationNotFoundException(terminalCertification)                                   
        db.Entry(lastCertification).CurrentValues.SetValues(terminalCertification);
    }
```

I have searched stackoverflow and found below code but there is not such ObjectStateManager in DBContext class.

```
ObjectStateManager stateMgr = db.ObjectStateManager;    
ObjectStateEntry stateEntry = stateMgr.GetObjectStateEntry(model);
stateEntry.SetModified();
```

what should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cast your DbContext to an IObjectContextAdapter which has the underlying ObjectContext and then use the ObjectStateManager off of that.

Comment: it throws this error:The ObjectStateManager does not contain an ObjectStateEntry with a reference to an object of type ...

Comment: Attach the entity to the DbContext first.

Comment: how to attach my object to DBContext?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/29/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-4-add-attach-and-entity-states.aspx

Comment: also, you can read about it here : http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/accessing-objectcontext-features-from-ef-4-1-dbcontext/

Answer (score 0):

Use the UpdateModel or [TryUpdateModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.tryupdatemodel.aspx) method inside your controller. If you are doing it outside of the controller then this will not work.